# How does - grep -E -o "average:.{0,5}" work

Tags: linux, grep

```
$ uptime
12:03:38 up 2 days, 19:03,  1 user,  load average:  1.87, 2.40, 2.20
$ uptime | grep -E -o "average:.{0,5}"
average: 1.53
```

I know that `-o =` shows only the matching part, but how does `.{0,5}` work here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-E` tells grep to use "extended regular expressions" instead of the default basic regular expressions matching.

`.` in a regular expression means "any character".
`{0,5}` is a repetition statement and means "the symbol before can be repeated 0 to 5 times".

`.{0,5}` means "match any 0 to 5 characters".

In your example, it matches  `1.53` which is in fact 5 characters long (note the space before the 1!).

Without `-E`, `.` would still match any character, but repetitions like `{0,5}` are not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

`{0,5}` it means match from `0` till `5` character if exists.

Comment: not only digits, as `.` matches any character. ANd in fact, in this example it matches a space and a period (and 3 digits)

Comment: Yes. That is actually I meant. Character. Poor choice of words. Thanks for your input.